# Print Out Every Combination of 2 Array Lists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to print out every combination of the two arrays I have below without luck. I have heard you can combine both of the lists to one and do it that way but we are supposed to do it with nested loops. It's also supposed to be in the exact order as displayed which is messing with me a bit. Any suggestions?

The expected output would be:

- 2 of Clubs
- 3 of Clubs
- 4 of Clubs
- 5 of Clubs
- etc....

`public class DeckPrinter {
private ArrayList<String> cards;
private ArrayList<String> suits;

public DeckPrinter(){
    cards = new ArrayList<>();
    suits = new ArrayList<>();

    cards.add("2");
    cards.add("3");
    cards.add("4");
    cards.add("5");
    cards.add("6");
    cards.add("7");
    cards.add("8");
    cards.add("9");
    cards.add("10");
    cards.add("Jack");
    cards.add("Queen");
    cards.add("King");
    cards.add("Ace");

    suits.add("Clubs");
    suits.add("Diamonds");
    suits.add("Hearts");
    suits.add("Spades");
}

public String getCards(){
   return cards.toString();
}

public String getSuits(){
    return suits.toString();
}

public void printDeck(){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < suits.size(); j++){
                System.out.println(cards.get(i) + " of " + suits.get(j));
            }
        }
}
}`

Comment: reorder your loops... iterate on suits and then cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < suits.size(); i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < cards.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(cards.get(j) + " of " + suits.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of the "for" in your code.

Comment: You could improve this answer by being a little more specific.  Reorder to what?  Something like "Switch the `for` line referencing `cards` with the one referencing `suits`